# WPF: Add a command to auto-generated by binding menu items

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, command

MVVM is used. I created separate menu 'Recent files' which gets its items from binding. It looks like that:

[image]

```
        <MenuItem Header="_Recent files" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles, Converter={StaticResource RecentFilesToListOfStringsConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" >
        </MenuItem>
```

Now, I would like to add Command to each of the those auto-generated items, which should get the path as command parameter and execute import file action by click.

Could you please suggest how can it be done in MVVM way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Again, found the solution by myself. I tried to put the command in wrong way like below, and it doesn't work:

```
            <MenuItem Header="_Recent files" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles, Converter={StaticResource RecentFilesToListOfStringsConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ImportRecentItemCommand}" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
```

Here is the right approach. Still don't understand how it works, have to learn WPF deeply!

```
            <MenuItem Header="_Recent files" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles, Converter={StaticResource RecentFilesToListOfStringsConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.ImportRecentItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
```

**EDIT: The final version**

XAML:

```
            <MenuItem Header="_Recent files" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles, Converter={StaticResource RecentFilesToListOfStringsConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.ImportRecentItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
```

ViewModel: MVVM Light Toolkit is used, RelayCommand goes from there:

```
        private ICommand _importRecentItemCommand;

        public ICommand ImportRecentItemCommand
        {
            get { return _importRecentItemCommand ?? (_importRecentItemCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(ImportRecentItemCommandExecuted)); }
        }

        private void ImportRecentItemCommandExecuted(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(parameter.ToString());
        }
```

Enjoy